# GUI in matlab, loop of images in axes

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

So I'm building a classifier of images. In the GUI a image loads and insert a value on a text box, and push a button. I'm having a problem loading the image in the axes. Because when the axes function is called the handles is zero(due to:% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called). And my problem is, how do I get to just call one image at a time for the axes.

The ideal solution, is I create a handles.images=imagedatastore, and every time I push the button I add to a counter(which I already have made) and then that give the indices to get the image from the datastore. My problem with this is that I can't get the first picture, because in the beginning the handles are empty. I have made the callfunction for the axes:

```
    % --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called
[pict_croped,Nphotos,Date_img] =getcropedimagages;

handles.img =pict_croped;
i=readimage(handles.img,1);
% axes(hObject)
imshow(i)
% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1
```

but this has two problems, first, I don't really want to call the function that creates the datastore all the time I push the button, second, I still can't get the indice of the counter to be in the function,if I have:

```
i=readimage(handles.img,handles.counter)
```

it will give me the error in the first time, of not having handles.counter

Any idea how to solve this?This is the first GUI I'm building.

Comment: Did you read the comment "% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1"?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is very clearly in the comment that GUIDE provides for you. The `handles` struct isn't populated until all `CreateFcn` have been run so you'll want to use the `OpeningFcn` to do any initialization of the graphics objects. You can then add any data you need to the `handles` struct and save it using `guidata` so that it's available from within all of your other callback functions.

```
function OpeningFcn(hObject, eventData, handles)

    [pict_croped,Nphotos,Date_img] = getcropedimagages;

    handles.img = pict_croped;
    i = readimage(handles.img,1);
    imshow(i, 'Parent', handles.haxes1)

    % "Save" the changes to the handles object
    guidata(hObject, handles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I end up with:
in the opening fucntion:

```
i = readimage(handles.img,handles.counter);
imshow(, 'Parent', handles.axes1)
```

and in the button call back:

```
i = readimage(handles.img,handles.counter);
imshow(i, 'Parent', handles.axes1)
```

inthe end is a very simple solution, I think I was just mind blocked over the first iteration...